# Using advanced textbox in place of MathJax

Tags: feature-request, edits, mathjax

MathJax is pretty hard for new users to understand and hence they are not able to ask their questions properly.

I suggest to use an advanced textbox in the ask question section so that they can easily type the question.

For example, see the [Desmos textbox](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: Maybe its useful but they'll need to learn that too. I think is better to learn by  *looking* at other posts in edit mode.

Comment: Then they will not prefer asking here if its so hard

Comment: I see lots of trouble too with text and code formating. I edit the posts for new users so they can learn how to properly do it (apart from the theory about it).

Comment: Related: *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* has the excellent *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)*